# Restriction of function respects tangent space of sub manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Might be a silly question, but I feel like the following should be true but I can't justify it.

If $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a differentiable function between two smooth manifolds, and there is some sub manifold $A$ of $M$ such that $f(A)=B$ where $B$ is some submanifold of $N$. Is it true that given $p\in A$, and the map $df_p:T_p M\rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$, we have $df_p(T_p A)\subset T_{f(p)}B$? If not, is there a situation where this does hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Take $v \in T_pA$: then there exists a smooth path $\gamma : (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to A$ with $\gamma(0) = 1$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. Now, as $\mathrm{d}f(p)\cdot v = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d} f\circ \gamma(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}$, and as $f\circ \gamma : (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to B$ is a smooth path with $f\circ\gamma(0) = f(p)$ and $(f\circ\gamma)'(0) = \mathrm{d}f(p)v$, it follows that $\mathrm{d}f(p)v \in T_{f(p)}B$.